# cannot convert query to action in playslick scala

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have the next code:

```
package learning

import infrastructure.user.UserTable
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice._
import play.api.Play
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.test._
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
import slick.lifted.{TableQuery}

class SlickSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerTest with Injecting  with MockitoSugar {

"Slick" should {
    "select all" in {

         val userTable = TableQuery[UserTable]
         val action = userTable.result // line with error
         ..
         db.run(action)
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm following the recommended steps to run a query after convert it to an action. However the line: **val action = userTable.result**
is producing this error:

> value result is not a member of slick.lifted.TableQuery[infrastructure.user.UserTable]

Comment: Would adding `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` help?

Comment: I tried, but didn't work, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this import:

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
```